# Thunderbird keeps asking PGP key

Tags: gnupg, thunderbird

Since this morning, Thunderbird keeps asking
«
Please enter the passphrase to unlock the openPGP secret key
...
»
in a popup every ~30 seconds.

I don't really remember what I did to trigger that.
Now I want to disable the popup.

How to say Thunderbird that I don't remember the passphrase and it should not ask me anymore?

In fact, the following "solved" the problem:

- quit Thunderbird
- rename the directory gnupg `mv .gnupg bak_gnupg`
- restart Thunderbird
- rename back `mv bak_gnupg .gnupg`
- quit/restart Thunderbird ad lib

Does someone understand what happened ?

Maybe related: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/252007